# Samba shared folder with setgid problem

Tags: permissions, samba, setgid

I am setting up a file server with a shared directory.  Inside, there are per-user folders that are readable by any user and a shared directory that is readable and writeable by any user.  The per-user folders are simple enough.  However, I am having some issues with the shared folder.  I performed the standard procedure for making a set GID folder:

```
# chown root shared
# chmod -R ug+rwX shared
# chgrp -R users shared
# find shared -type d -exec chmod g+s "{}" \;
# find shared -type d -exec setfacl -m "default:group::rwx" "{}" \;
```

After ensuring all users are in the 'users' group, this works perfectly via direct console login, ssh, rsync, etc.  However, there are some issues with samba.

With the default samba config, the SGID bit and GID are propagated, but new files and folders do not have the group write bit set.  This appears to be because the ACL is being ignored.  According to [Samba Ignoring POSIX ACLs](https://serverfault.com/questions/459479/samba-ignoring-posix-acls), the solution is to add `vfs objects = acl_xattr` to smb.conf.  When I set that, the group write permission is correctly set.  However, the group is then set to the user's primary group instead of the group of the parent directory, which rather defeats the purpose of the set GID bit.  I tried the other smb.conf adjustments noted in the link (`map acl inherit = yes`, `store dos attributes = yes`, and `inherit acls = yes`), but these had no effect.  What's the proper way to make this work?

Comment: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=65659

Answer (score 0):

To set group, user and permissions for new files and folders, I use this config on the server (in `smb.conf`):

```
[shared-folder]
   writeable = yes
   force user  = "user"
   force group = "users"
   create mask = 0664
   force create mode = 0664
   directory mask = 0775
   force directory mode = 0755
```

You could handle the common folder this way, through a separate shared folder.

**Note:** as pointed out in the comments, this setup may not be compatible with ACLs. I would recommend doing this only if you are going to rely on UNIX permissions only.

Comment: Ah, but I don't want to set the group write bit on the whole share, just on one subdirectory.  And I likewise don't want to force a user or group on the whole share.

Comment: this is what i do (on a separate share from user shares) but according to one of the answers [to this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/459479/samba-ignoring-posix-acls) the `force` and `mask` parameters are incompatible with ACLs.

Comment: @quixotic Good point: my assumption was that with this setup one would not need ACLs, but there could be other reasons for needing them.

Answer (score 0):

If `vfs objects = acl_xattr`, then automatically `inherit acls = yes`, as per the man pages describing `inherit acls` in `smb.conf`:

> Note that using the VFS modules **acl_xattr** or acl_tdb which store
> native Windows as meta-data will automatically turn this option on for
> any share for which they are loaded, as they require this option to
> emulate Windows ACLs correctly.

And once `inherit acls` is turned on, the unix mode used to create new files/directories will be 0777 (effectively zeroing out the `setgid` bit):

> Enabling this option sets the unix mode to 0777, thus guaranteeing
> that default directory acls are propagated.

Explicitly specifying `inherit acls = no` alongside `vfs objects = acl_xattr` seems to work, but they're probably not meant to be used together this way and may have unknown/hidden side effects.